# Appending ng-repeat into HTML element dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, appendchild

I trying to append ng-repeat into my HTML div on load. 
It recognizes  the ng-repeat, however the index value isn't displaying as it should

HTML

```
<div id="myInnerCarousel"></div>
```

controller:

```
var myCarousel = document.getElementById('myInnerCarousel');
var newItem = document.createElement("div");
newItem.setAttribute("class","item");

var newData = document.createElement("div");
newData.setAttribute("class", "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3");
newData.setAttribute("ng-repeat", "mat in " + arr);

//Create individual values seperately
var newMaterialName = document.createElement("h4");
var nameNode = document.createTextNode("{{mat.Name}}");
newMaterialName.appendChild(nameNode);
//Append everything together

newData.appendChild(newMaterialName);
newItem.appendChild(newData);
myCarousel.appendChild(newItem);
```

However the result is this:

https://gyazo.com/00b76c6b910d4c6701059d404783f720

It got the right idea of displaying my array, however angular isn't displaying h4 right.

EDIT: imtrying to achieve this in my html:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="mat in array1">
        <h4>{{mat.Name}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="mat in array2">
        <h4>{{mat.Name}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to use angular's $compile function on the newly created element.

Comment: I agree with @RabbiShuki here.  This doesn't seem like an angular approach to whatever problem you are trying to solve.  Why did you settle on the idea of doing DOM manipulation on page load like this? Is there some reason that your HTML code can't already be in your template file?

Comment: it's somewhat clear what you are expecting as an end result, but you still haven't really described why you are trying to do this in such a non angular way.  DOM Manipulation is exactly the practice angular was created to save you from, so using DOM Manipulation to create Angular elements is counter to the framework design.

Answer (score 2):

Lets simply state that this is not the way to do it.

A better and more angular way would be (assuming your apps name is `app`).

> HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="mat in array">
            <h4>{{mat.Name}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Angular Controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.array = [{Name: 'abc'}, {Name: 'def'}]; // or whatever your data looks like.
});
```

Comment: Hi I understand fully. Please view my edit in the post to get a better understanding of what im trying to achieve

Comment: In html code, yes. but visually I get what you see in the link above

Comment: Seems to me like your angular app is not wired up correctly. A few common errors might be, 1. forgetting to add `ng-app` to `body`. 2. forgetting to add `controller` to `div`. and more. try checking the console in chrome and see if there are any errors there, might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically added component should be compiled using angular. you can use `$compile` function of angular. **Below is working code.**

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/34625/)

```
function TodoCtrl($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.arr = [{Name: "Dynamically Added cowermponent"}];
    var myCarousel = document.getElementById('myInnerCarousel');
    var newItem = document.createElement("div");
    newItem.setAttribute("class","item");

    var newData = document.createElement("div");
    newData.setAttribute("class", "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3");
    newData.setAttribute("ng-repeat", "mat in arr");

    //Create individual values seperately
    var newMaterialName = document.createElement("h4");
    var nameNode = document.createTextNode("{{mat.Name}}");
    newMaterialName.appendChild(nameNode);
    //Append everything together

    newData.appendChild(newMaterialName);
    newItem.appendChild(newData);
    myCarousel.appendChild(newItem);
    $compile(newItem)($scope);
}
```

Comment: Hi @KennyNguyen, I have added the code that dynamically add ng-repeat to html.

Comment: Nice answer, I hear about `$compile` first time, and wow working, Your post really helped me to understand more about angularjs.

Comment: Feeling fanastic happiness hearing your comment !